# RaisePostBackEvent: raise custom or default postback event method based upon the user control that caused the postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET page that contains both javascript and ASP.NET user controls. When a postback is executed, I use the `RaisePostBackEvent` method to determine which method should be called. That way, it's possible to trigger a postback via javascript. For example, I load a User Control via a postback that was triggered via javascript. However, the events of such a user control can't be raised via postback anymore, because the `RaisePostBackEvent` method is called, rather than de default postback behaviour. So how can I call the default postback behaviour on a user control, from within the `RaisePostBackEvent` method?

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent (string eventArgument) {
    string eventTarget = Request ["__EVENTTARGET"];
    if (eventTarget == UniqueID) {
        eventArgument = Request ["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        Action action = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action>(eventArgument);
        if (action.name == "display") Display(action.argument);
        else if (action.name == "edit") Edit(action.edit);
    }
    else {
        // Control control = GetPostBackControl(this.Page);
        // !!! Raise the postback event on the control.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this statement in the `OnInit` event method of the user control containing the javascript:

```
protected override void OnInit (EventArgs e) {
    Page.RegisterRequiresRaiseEvent(this);
}
```

When this statement is removed, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could put postback logic into a separate method:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoButtonLogic();
}
```

so you could call it also from RaisePostback:

```
...
else 
{
   DoButtonLogic();
}
```

Comment: I know, but the user controls have too many events for that, and some of the user controls are just DLL's that I can't customize.

Comment: Why are you using this approach instead of ASP.NET AJAX's UpdatePanel?

Comment: I have no experience with UpdatePanel. I'm reading documentation about it right now. How would I use it in order to solve my problem?

Comment: I would put all controls inside an UpdatePanel and get advantage of the automatic refresh of the page. So all of your controls could be ASP.NET controls, but the whole page would be AJAX enabled.